# Computer screen goes black after updating graphic driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

Recently I had updated my AMD graphic card.Catalyst Control Center says there is no update available but AMD Gaming Evolved notify me an update is available. They direct me to this [website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows%207%20-%2064). I downloaded it, uninstall my current ATI Catalyst Control Manager, restarted my laptop, installed new driver and restarted again. But after the windows 7 logo, my screen stays completely black. Any idea guys? Thanks.

[EDITED]

My SysInfos:

```
ASUS A43S, 
Intel i7, 
RADEON Graphics HD 6730M 2GB, 
Windows 7 64-bit.
```

Comment: We need more specifics.

Comment: ASUS A43S, Intel i7, RADEON Graphics HD 6730M 2GB, Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: You should update your question so it includes that information.

Comment: Have you loaded Windows in Safe Mode and tried to roll back the drivers?